# Python vowels constant

Tags: python, python-3.x, alphabet

Is there a Python library that contains a variable which contains vowels, e.g. `'aeiou'`, `['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']` or something like that? in the `string` library there is  `ascii_lowercase` variable with the English alphabet, but extracting vowels and consonants from it requires hard-coding the `'aeiou'`-like constant. Can we avoid that?

**Edit**: Answering to questions in comments:
Yes, the use-case is to replace

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
vowels = 'aeiou'
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
```

with something less error-prone. What I use now is:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
vowels = 'aeiou'
consonants = ''.join(c for c in alphabet if c not in vowels)
```

But ideally, I would like to be able to just import these constants:

```
from [lib] import alphabet, vowels, consonants
```

Thank's for the feedback!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Pattern matching? Please post the necessary details.

Comment: You've already included this string constant twice in this question. What is the problem with including it in your code?

Comment: Won't ever happen. People wouldn't be able to agree about 'y'. Plus it's just not important.

Comment: What exactly is your usecase? Do you just want to replace the `vowels = "aeiou"` with some import, or do you care about different definitions of "vowel" in different locales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no predefined variable for vowels because they are defined based on phonology/pronunciation and vary between language. Some letters are either vowels or consonants depending on their placement in words. Saying that 'aeiou' are vowels is more of a reductive shorthand on the concept than an actual definition.  You will need to make your own constant in accordance with your use case.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

A vowel list is not in the standard python library, but a quick way generate a vowel list is:

`vowels = set("aeiou")`

Comment: That's not a list but a set.

Comment: `vowels = list("aeiou")` will generate a vowel list